# How to print a fread()?

Tags: c, printf, fread

I swear, I have researched a lot before asking here, but could not find anything that could help.

I have a file with the extension .pcm that contains data (in numbers) that I want to use later with some operations. For now, just to see what the data is, I want only to printf its contents. It probably should be read as type short, since I have had used this same file in MatLab before.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    short input[1000];
    int i;
    fp=fopen("Sweep_10_310.pcm", "rb"); 
    if (!fp) { 
        printf("Could not open file!\n"); 
        return 1; 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",fread(input,sizeof(short),1,fp));
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The console prints only zeroes.

If I change the file for a different text file (just to test the code) and change all "short" to "char", I get the same result. Which is the ideal way to fread a file?

** Edit:
In the end, my file was actually empty :(
Anyways, the answers here work and a lot were learned

Comment: You're opening a `txt` file, but opening it as a binary. Are the numbers stored in text (i.e. you could open it with notepad and see the numbers) or in binary?

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I actually forgot to change that extension. It is suposed to be .pcm. While this should not change a lot, probably would make difference.

Comment: Additionally to the answers (which explain how to fix your code, but not what's currently happening): You probably see `0` (instead of the number of items read) because you use the `d` conversion specifier for a `size_t` argument. Use `"%zu"` instead.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question of whether the numbers themselves are in binary or text form. If they're text, you should not be using `fread`

Comment: They are probably in binary form since they are generated by Ocenaudio Software.

Comment: Perhaps the contents of the file does not exist.

Comment: BLUEPIXY is actually right. I'm so ashamed. I've probably messed up in some point writing it over with none content. I'm really sorry. Althought I learned A LOT here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   fread(input, sizeof(short), 1, fp); 
   printf("%hd", input[0]);
}
```

Or better option:

```
fread(input, sizeof(short), 100, fp);
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{ 
   printf("%hd", input[i]);
}
```

---

In your case:

`printf("%d",fread(input,sizeof(short),1,fp));`

You are printing output of `fread`, but it doesn't contain data read, it returns amount of data read. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/).

Returned value:

> The total number of elements successfully read is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this did not work. Now I understand better how fread works, but the output of the code is a lot of repeated numbers that changes every time I run the code (they probably are addresses)

Comment: @Mark, thanks for comment, now I see that I missed pointer <-> variable logic, try now.

Comment: I'm so ashamed. Both you codes do really work. The problem was that my file was actually empty. I've probably messed up in some point writing it over with none content. I'm really sorry.
Thanks you very much!

Comment: @Mark, if you found an issue you either can accept the most valuable answer or delete your question, because you found out that problem is _something else_, this case empty data file.

Comment: I see. I will accept your answer because is simpler and even with the empty data file I've found nothing similar in my research on the internet. Thank you again.

Comment: @ST3 Your "better option" ignores the number of elements read. You are quite possibly printing uninitialized array elements.

Comment: @TRKemp can't deny that, but looking into OP question, it looks like 100 is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

`sizeof *input`gives the number of bytes in a single array element; it's equivalent to `sizeof (short)`.

```
short input[NUM_ITEMS] = {0}; 
...
int itemsRead = fread( input, sizeof *input, NUM_ITEMS, fp );
for ( int i = 0; i < itemsRead; i++ )
{
  /**
   * use %hd format specifier for short values
   */
  printf( "%hd ", input[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

If `itemsRead` is 0, then you've either hit EOF or there was an error on input:

```
if ( !itemsRead )
{
  if ( feof( fp ) )
    fprintf( stderr, "hit end-of-file\n" );
  else
    fprintf( stderr, "error during read\n" );
}
```

Comment: +1 for a complete answer.  Maybe: `if (ferror(fp) fprintf( stderr, "error during read\n");`?   Could it be possible for both `feof(fp)` and `ferror(fp)` to be false/true?  (`fp == NULL`, `NUM_ITEMS == 0`, `fp` is a serial device and no data available, maybe other odd-ball cases.)

Comment: Nice approach, it works. I`ve learned a lot with this code in particular :)

Answer (score 2):

fread() will return *the number of items reads* and not the actual data being read. So if you printf() the return value of fread(), you won't get the actual item read. Instead, you must printf() your "input", the buffer into which fread is copying the contents it reads. If an error ocurrs, use ferror() to ascertain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`fread` returns the number of items read or zero. You also must use `feof` because `fread` does NOT distinguish between EOF and error.

This could be better for you, reading byte after byte:

```
int c;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("Sweep_10_310.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I actually have to read numbers, but not characters. I typed it wrong in the first post, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int j;
```

...

```
j = fread(input, sizeof(short), 100, fp); 

for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
   printf(" %d", input[i]);
}
```

Comment: Suggest " %d", else all the digits print together.

Comment: It works, but I had to declare j before putting fread in it, probably because its C and not C++.

Answer (score 0):

After using `fread()`, note its return value and use that to determine how much was read.  Use the size of `input` to determine how much to attempt to read at once.

```
#define N (1000)
short input[N];
...
size_t num_of_elements_read;
while ((num_of_elements_read = fread(input, sizeof input[0], N, fp)) > 0) {
  for (size_t j = 0; j < num_of_elements_read; j++) {
    printf(" %hd", input[j]);  // %d may also work, %hd is the better format
  }
}
```